# Only print on the first column of csv

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this code but I am having issues when the data I am scraping has commas. I want it only show on the first column but when there's a comma, the data appears on the 2nd column. Is it possible to scrape and print it on the first column only of csv without using panda? Thanks

```
i = 1
for url in urls:
    print(f'Scraping the URL no {i}')
    i += 1
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    links = []
    for text in soup.find('div',class_='entry-content').find_all('div',class_='streak'):
        link = text.a['href']
        text = text.a.text
        links.append(link)
        with open("/Users/Rex/Desktop/data.csv", "a") as file_object:
            file_object.write(text)
            file_object.write("\n")
```

Comment: You want the first column to include the full text, including commas?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes. I want the data to appear on first column only, including the commas and other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files have rules for escaping commas within a single column so that they are not mistakenly interpreted as a new column. This escaping can be applied automatically if you use the `csv` module. You really only need to open the file once, so with a few more tweaks to your code

```
import csv

with open("/Users/Rex/Desktop/data.csv", "a", newline=None) as file_object:
    csv_object = csv.writer(file_object)
    i = 1
    for url in urls:
        print(f'Scraping the URL no {i}')
        i += 1
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        links = []
        for text in soup.find('div',class_='entry-content').find_all('div',class_='streak'):
            link = text.a['href']
            text = text.a.text.strip()
            # only record if we have text
            if text:
                links.append(link)
                csv_object.writerow([text])
```

NOTE: This code is skipping links that do not have text.

Comment: I have updated the details of the script. Please take a look.

Comment: @Mia - We prefer minimal examples here. Your update didn't change the essence of the problem - just added code that wasn't part of the problem. I'll update my answer to match, but for future reference, try to keep the code tightly focused on the problem. As an example, the href stuff wasn't really part of the problem and could have been removed in your question.

Comment: This one worked but there's a vacant row after one data. How to make it appear like there is no vacant row? Thanks btw.

Comment: @Mia - By "vacant row" I assume you get the comma but no data. That would suggest that in one of your documents, `text` is an empty string. I don't know enough about your problem to know the best solution, but it sounds like you could check for empty and skip that writerow. If there should always be text, then you could test and raise an error.